# Difference between NameVirtualHost and Listen apache server

Tags: apache, virtualhost

What is difference between

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and

```
Listen 80
```

Also where do I add these? (in ports.conf or in a virtualHosts file)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you start reading the freely available and very precise documentation.

Comment: Question was already answered: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92380